# WinRT app incomplete resuming (images become solid black)

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a XAML C# based universal app (currently focusing on WP8.1)
The main page of my app is really complex with 3 pivots each with grids, images, borders, buttons, Listview etc
The problem is sometimes when I resume my app after I do some other stuff (like call, game or other memory intensive task), some of the images and even some listview items become blank! It's like a partial resume i.e. OS did not terminate the app even though some of the memory allocated might have been discarded leading to incomplete restoration.

Containers for visual element (and alignment of elements) is correct. It's just the content that becomes blank.

Is there anyway I could correct this? I won't mind OS to terminate the app in low memory situation but seriously this improper resume is bad.

Similar thread but hasn't got any proper answer [Why do my images sometimes reload (and WriteableBitmaps disappear) on resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433370/why-do-my-images-sometimes-reload-and-writeablebitmaps-disappear-on-resume)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I encounter the same problem.

Comment: I'm also facing similiar problem - some of the images fail to load.

Comment: Would need some sort of repro to look further into this!

Comment: What Windows Phone version exactly? Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1(8.10.14xxx) may doesn't have the problem in our experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Benjamin in comment above, this problem seems to have been fixed since Windows phone 8.1 Update 1. I am not seeing this issue anymore.

Comment: still I am facing the similar problem, any solution to fix this issue.